# Pass additional Data to Searchable using voiceSearch Android

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing, google-voice-search

In order to pass additional Data I use 
`@Override onQueryTextSubmitString query)` and `intent.putExtra()`, which works fine when the user enters  the text in the searchwidget. But it seems the function is not called when the users uses voiceSearch. Is there any way to pass Data to the Searchable Activity using voiceSearch?

Thanks in Advance for any suggestions.